# is there a http binder for spring cloud stream?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a service that needs to be modelled as stream app ( the service offers sync and async api s for the same use cases currently ).  I am exploring if the the actual processing can be modelled as a stream app . As processing stages remain same - the real difference is the service interface ( http vs messaging protocols) .
With that context I am exploring spring cloud stream as it seems to abstract away binders and processors. But to support sync api i will need the following :-

- Sync Api ==   Http Binder <--> (req/resp) Processors
- Async Api ==  RabbitMQ/Kafka Binder --> (pub/sub) Processors --> RabbitMQ/Kafka Binder

There will be 2 deployables which is fine and Processors can be packaged as a library to be used by both these artefacts. Now I do not see any Http Binder in Spring Cloud Stream, is there anything i can use? Does this flow look alright?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are implementations of HTTP. Please check links below:

**Stream Applications**
https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications

**Reusable Functions**
java.util.Supplier
https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/blob/master/functions/supplier/http-supplier/README.adoc

java.util.Function
https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/blob/master/functions/function/http-request-function/README.adoc

**Reusable Spring Cloud Stream Applications**
Source
https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/blob/master/applications/source/http-source/README.adoc
Processor
https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/blob/master/applications/processor/http-request-processor/README.adoc